# jquery stops working after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use this [plugin](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples/multiple-instances.html) to show multiple instances 
on the same page. But when i make ajax call and load a part of the page the timer stops running. Maybe it is lost from DOM. Can anyone suggest what goes wrong please ? 
i tried to call the function every time when i call ajax (it is working properly) but i think it is not the right solution.

here is the jquery code:

```
$('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this), 
  finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
  $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
    $(this).find('.day').html(event.strftime('%D'));
    $(this).find('.hour').html(event.strftime('%H'));
    $(this).find('.minute').html(event.strftime('%M'));
    $(this).find('.seconds').html(event.strftime('%S'));
  });
});

$(document).on('click', '.reload-img', function(e) {
          $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "reload__ajax.php",
           dataType:"html",
           data: { lang:lang, confirmed:confirmed, result_id:result_id },
           success: function(data){ 

                $('ul[data-id='+result_id+']').html(data).fadeIn(1000);
           }
         });
});
```

Comment: Can you post your AJAX code as well please?

Comment: maybe because `data` is not a string?

Comment: Have you checked your console for error logs after page execution? An error in JavaScript may stop the any further excutions in browser's JavaScript engine.

Comment: also, what is `result_id`? where is it defined?

Comment: i dont think ajax call is related with the question. i make an ajax call and reload a part of my page which contains this time countdown plugin. when the new part is loaded the plugin is not working. that's all.